# Is there any way to classify text based on some given keywords using python?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, text-classification

i been trying to learn a bit of machine learning for a project that I'm working in. At the moment I managed to classify text using SVM with sklearn and spacy having some good results, but i want to not only classify the text with svm, I also want it to be classified based on a list of keywords that I have. For example: If the sentence has the word fast or seconds I would like it to be classified as performance.

I'm really new to machine learning and I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are already taking a portion of your data, classifying it manually and then using the result as your training data for the SVM algorithm.

If yes, then you could just append your list of keywords (features) and desired classifications (labels) to your training data. If you are not doing it already, I'd recommend using the SnowballStemmer on your training data features.

Comment: Oh,i was thinking about adding the keywords into the training data, but I wasn't sure if that would work. Ima try it and see what happens. Thank you so much.